# Do I need "have" here?

Tags: word-order, auxiliary-verbs

> Was it specifically mentioned as part of their teaching or they **have** just
>   happened not to have killed anyone?

Do I need **have** there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need the *have*, but it’s because you need inversion:

> Was it specifically mentioned as part of their teaching or *have they* just happened not to have killed anyone?

Comment: Why do I need an inversion there? Is the "was it" inversion not enough for forming a question here?

Comment: @brilliant It’s because of the *or*.  Both parts require inversion.  “Did you do this or did she do that?” “Are you going or are we staying?”

Comment: But why then we don't need it in "Is it an apple or a pear?"? I don't think we need to say "Is it an apple or **is it** a pear?"

Comment: @brilliant Yes, that’s right.  But if you have a verb in the `or` part, then you need inversion.

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you. What do you think about a case with comma? This is what Alok has just brought up in his answer.

Comment: @brilliant Alok’s answer is wrong.  It doesn’t scan in English.

Comment: Just a small follow-up question: Could I say "Was it specifically mentioned as part of their teaching or **did** they just happen not to have killed anyone?"?

Comment: @brilliant Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score -1):

You could split up the sentence with a comma, I think then you won't need 'have':

Was it specifically mentioned as part of their teaching, or they just happened not to have killed anyone?

Comment: That doesn’t scan in English. Sorry.